# how to put to work Ionic generator?

Tags: ionic-framework, generator, yeoman

I have an Ionic app running with the basics of Ionic and running it in the browser by doing `ionic serve`, but I want some new stuff and run it trough the `grunt serve` command, also has the feature for JSLint, I am already using this `scss` this: https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic/ and I see that have everything I want, how do I install that in my project?

Take into account that my project is almost done, I have almost 85 % already done.

Is this the part I need to follow up:

> **Upgrading**
>
> Make sure you've committed (or backed up) your local changes and install the latest version of the generator via npm install -g generator-ionic, then go ahead and re-run yo ionic inside your project's directory.
>
> The handsome devil is smart enough to figure out what files he is attempting to overwrite and prompts you to choose how you would like to proceed. Select Y for overwriting your Gruntfile.js and bower.json to stay up-to-date with the latest workflow goodies and front-end packages.

does this will bring some complications ? is there something else I need to know ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the same generator and enjoy using it. With that said, I would not recommend starting to use a generator until you've made a complete backup of your project.

Even then, I'd recommend creating a brand new project using the generator then migrating your existing code into the newly generated project. While migrating, you should be modifying your code to match the generator conventions as you go. This gives you the most control and will make sure that you learn the conventions of the new project structure. Upgrading instructions are really meant for people who already use the generator and are just upgrading to a new version of the generator. They are not applicable to you.

Comment: got it, thanks. What is the best way to install manually JSLint ?

Comment: It really depends on your existing build process. If you're using grunt or gulp then there are plugins for that, if not, you can always using the command line version of jslint. The install command is: sudo npm install -g jslint